# How to switch SCSS format when copying with eCSStractor?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, vscode-extensions

I do not know how to disable SCSS class format for now.

I want to switch from this :

```css
.header {

  &__row {}

  &__logo {}

  &__nav {}

}
```

to this :

```css
.header__row {
  
}
```

I tried to look in the settings, enabled SCSS but nothing helps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a nested stylesheet for preprocessors. To generate CSS, do one of the following actions :

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to launch command palette and choose :

   - eCSStractor Run (Without BEM Nesting)

Or

2. Go to the extension settings and make sure `ecsstractor_port.bem_nesting` is set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer but the problem remains even with the option "eCSS tractor run without BEM".

**This is what I have**

[image]

**And this is how I want it to be**

[image]